# Java executable jar cannot be executed as ./program.jar on OS X

Tags: java, linux, macos, jar

Using Linux, I run some programs I've written in Java by compressing them in a jar with a manifest file and then placing them in a personal directory that has been added to my $PATH as follows: 
`program.jar file2 file2`. It works well in any directory I point my console to, I can even do `program.jar file1 | less` or `program.jar file1 > output.txt`.They work as if they were bin console programs.

However on OS X I cannot replicate the same behavior, I am forced to run them with `java -jar program.jar` otherwise it would say `-bash program.jar: cannot execute binary file`

Is there a way to make a jar behave as they do in Linux on OS X?

**EDITED:**

ANSWER thanks to [Jean-Baptiste Yunès](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719263/jean-baptiste-yun%C3%A8s):

---

From the command line

If you build a new Java Swing application using one of the Xcode Organizer’s templates, Xcode automatically generates an application bundle complete with a default `Info.plist` file. You can fine-tune the `Info.plist` file directly in Xcode or with Property List Editor. For more information on using Xcode for Java development, see Xcode Help (available from the Help menu in Xcode).

If you want to turn your existing Java application into an OS X Java application, use the Jar Bundler application available in `/Developer/Applications/Utilities`. It allows you to take existing `.class` or `.jar` files and wrap them as application bundles. Information about Jar Bundler, including a tutorial, is provided in *Jar Bundler User Guide*.

To build a valid application bundle from the command-line, for example, in a shell script or an Ant file, you need to follow these steps:

Set up the correct directory hierarchy. The top level directory should be named with the name of your application with the suffix `.app`.

There should be a Contents directory at the root of the application bundle. It should contain a MacOS directory and a Resources directory. A Java directory should be inside of the Resources directory.

The directory layout should look like this:

```
YourApplicationName.app/
```

```
    Contents/
```

```
        MacOS/
```

```
        Resources/
```

```
            Java/
```

Copy the `JavaApplicationStub` file from `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/MacOS/` into the `MacOS` directory of your application bundle.

Make an `Info.plist` file in the `Contents` directory of your application bundle. You can start with an example from an existing Java application (such as Jar Bundler) and modify it or generate a completely new one from scratch. Note that the application bundle does not launch unless you have set the correct attributes in this property list, especially the `MainClass` key.

Make a `PkgInfo` file in the `Contents` directory. It should be a plain text file. If you have not registered a creator code with ADC, the contents should be `APPL????`. If you have registered a creator code replace the `????` with your creator code.

Put your application’s icon file into the `Contents/Resources/` directory. Use Icon Composer in `Developer/Applications/Utilities` for help creating your icon file.

Copy your Java `.jar` or `.class` files into `Contents/Resources/Java/`.

Set the bundle bit Finder attribute with `SetFile`, found in `/Developer/Tools/`. For example, `/Developer/Tools/SetFile -a B YourApplicationName.app`. For more information on `SetFile`, see the man page.

After these steps, you should have a double-clickable application bundle that contains your Java application.

Comment: Note that it is _not_ standard behavior for a Unix system to be able to execute jar files as standard programs.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so too, I wonder what makes it work, that's what I'm trying to figure. I also started porting my code to C++.

Comment: This is most likely a specific setting in the particular Linux distribution you are using.  Making executable java archives is an art.  I would suggest you look into the various solutions before leaving java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSX Apps need to be bundled, so read [Oracle Java OSX Distribution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) and [Apple Java Bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html). After that you will be able to launch them via command-line (just ask to run the stub by hand).

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question with your answer. Salut ! I am a P7 Computational Linguist, I assisted to your course on System and Language C, It was really good.